# Migrate IRouter usage to ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, migration

I'm reading through Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2 and one of the chapters about advanced routing features includes a mechanism whereby you can implement two-way legacy URL handling via `IRouter`. The gist of it is this:

Suppose you have a "legacy" URL like `"/article/Windows_3.1_Overview.html"`

Using a custom `IRouter` implementation, Core 2.0 lets you:

1. Direct that legacy URL to a specific action (e.g. `Legacy/GetLegacyUrl`) *while passing in the URL as a parameter* as so:

```
public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context) 
{
  string requestedUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.TrimEnd('/');

  if (urls.Contains(requestedUrl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
  {
    context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Legacy";
    context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "GetLegacyUrl";
    context.RouteData.Values["legacyUrl"] = requestedUrl;
    await mvcRoute.RouteAsync(context); // mvcRoute is an instance of MvcRouteHandler
  }
}
```

2. Generate *that same URL* using a tag helper: (`<a asp-route-legacyurl="/article/Windows_3.1_Overview.html">Old Link</a>`) using the following:

```
public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context) 
{
  if (context.Values.ContainsKey("legacyUrl")) 
  {
    string url = context.Values["legacyUrl"] as string;

    if (urls.Contains(url)) 
    {
      return new VirtualPathData(this, url);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

My question is: how do I do that in Core 3.0? I've tried this approach but there is no MvcRouteHandler anymore. I've tried implementing `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` like so:

```
public async override ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext,
  RouteValueDictionary values)
{
  string requestedUrl = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.TrimEnd('/');

  return await Task.FromResult(new RouteValueDictionary()
  {
    ["controller"] = "Legacy",
    ["action"] = "GetLegacyUrl",
    ["legacyUrl"] = requestedUrl
  });
}
```

... but as far as I've read, this only works one way. It's also the only thing mentioned in Microsoft's 2.2 -> 3.0 migration guide. I've tried to just literally map the URL using

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "",
  template: route,
  defaults: new { controller = "Legacy", action = "GetLegacyUrl", legacyUrl = route });
```

But this also doesn't generate the legacy URL, instead opting for `Legacy/GetLegacyUrl/?legacyUrl=%2Farticle%2FWindows_3.1_Overview.html`

I'm not really sure how else I can achieve this and I've been racking my brain and the documentation for several hours now. *"Routing in ASP.NET Core"* didn't help, neither did *"Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0"*.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I just can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the default mvc route handler using **routes.DefaultHandler**

In LegacyRoute.cs file, change your constructor signature from

public LegacyRoute(IServiceProvider services, params string[] targetUrls)

To

public LegacyRoute(IRouter routeHandler, params string[] targetUrls)

In Startup.cs file, add the route like this given below

routes.Routes.Add(new LegacyRoute(routes.DefaultHandler, "/articles/Windows_3.1_Overview.html", "/old/.NET_1.0_Class_Library"));